# How do I put my firestore data into a table?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```js
export function ListData() {
  const [dataList,setDataList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() =>{
      async function callData(){
         const result = await GetAllDataOnce()
         return result
      }
     setDataList(callData())
   },[])
  async function GetAllDataOnce() {
     const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "repos"));
     var data = [];
     querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        data.push({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data()
        })
     })
    return data;
  }
 return (
      <table>
        {dataList.map(returndata => (
          <tr key={returndata.id}>
            <td>{returndata.data}</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </table>
)}
```

Here is the data I am working with: [image]
This is using react with firebase firestore. I want to display each name with their respective desc, icon, and repo. I am getting error

> table.js:37 Uncaught TypeError: dataList.map is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to debug by printing value from the function callData, then check if it is an array.

```
async function callData(){
   const result = await GetAllDataOnce()
console.log(result) 
console.log(typeof result)
    return result
}
```